# htaccess rule does not accept dot

Tags: php, html, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a problem with my htaccess rules.
i have this rule in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^u/([a-z-0-9-_]+)$ user.php?id=$1
```

and its work just fine but when i write username with dot (.) its does not work
and the browser say the page not found
i looked up the internet and nothing helped me
so can anyone here help ?

Comment: Use `^u/([^/]+)$` where `[^/]+` will match *any* 1 or more chars other than `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[a-z-0-9-_]` pattern only matches lowercase ASCII letters, `-` and `_`. If you replace it with a *negated character class* `[^/]` it will match any char but `/`.

Use

```
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)$ user.php?id=$1
```